# Can you give mathematical illustration of stopping of time at the event horizon for a far observer in asymptotically minkowski spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity

And does it apply to null curves too?

Answer (score 1):

Given the Schwarzschild metric's line element:

$$ds^2 = -\left( 1 - \frac{2GM}{r} \right)dt^2 + \left( 1 - \frac{2GM}{r} \right)^{-1} dr^2 + r^2 d\Omega^2$$

an infalling observer will measure her time to be the proper time $\tau$ defined as $d\tau^2 = -ds^2$. Note that 't' is the time coordinate for an asymptotic observer. Putting to zero the spatial coordinates for an infalling observer and comparing the two different frames, we see that:

$$d\tau = \sqrt{ 1 - \frac{2GM}{r} } dt$$

which shows that as $r \rightarrow 2GM$, a finite proper time interval of $d\tau$ corresponds to a larger and larger time interval $dt$ for an observer far away. The result holds for null curves too.

Comment: If the result holds for null curves too, does it mean that even light will take infinite amount with respect to far observer for reaching the event horizon?

Comment: @gaganarora Yes